# Validation of dynamic fields in a MVC and field metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My model looks like

```
public class Template
{
    Id
    Title
    List<Field> Fields
}
```

The “Field” Entity contains information like Name, Caption, Type (TextBox/Select/Radio), Options, and validation rules (Range, Required, string length). How to set Field Properties from HTML helper??

The standard validation in MVC is based on DataAnnotations, but I wants to validate (Both client and Server Side) the form dynamically based on Field Metadata which is dynamic and configurable. How to set Field Properties from HTML helper so that I can use it in controller for validation?

Comment: Create partial class of Fields and decorate all possible property with DataAnnotations.

Comment: For the server side validation you have to identify the property and remove from modelstate before valid check